# Screen Flash Behavior

Tags: macos, accessibility

I have an annoying new behavior on my MBP 13" running Lion (10.7.4) that I don't know what I did to provoke.  I am familiar with so-called visual bells in terminals, but I've noticed a similar effect happening in *any* window in my OS X session - not just in Terminal.  I've researched this and there appears to be a setting in *System Preferences -> Universal Access -> Hearing* where you can enable a screen flash in place of an alert sound.  However, this is unchecked on my system.

Any ideas how I can correct this?  I'm going to seize out soon if I can't figure out how to disable it...ugh.

---

EDIT:  In response to the comments/questions below, I have confirmed that the plist also shows this setting disabled.  I'm not sure what the advantage to removing the plist file and logging out/in would be.

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist|grep -A1 flashScreen 
<key>flashScreen</key> <false/>
```

Comment: Does it appear like the flash shown by the test screen flash button?

Comment: Yes it does look the same.

Comment: Have you tried something like deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist` and logging out and back in?

Comment: plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist|grep -A1 flashScreen
 <key>flashScreen</key>
 <false/>

Comment: The only harm that can come from removing this particular plist is that you'll need to reconfigure any UniversalAccess settings that you actually want.  The *benefit* to removing it is that it will rule out strange configuration issues.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your system sound muted or volume turned all the way down?  Even for the non-hearing-impaired the Mac will use visual bells (at least some of the time) when sound output is turned off.